# Two masses connected by spring moving in a plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring, non-linear-systems, linear-systems

Is the 2-dimensional motion of two masses connected by a spring non-linear?

As far as I see it, the magnitude of the force on each mass is proportional to the spring's displacement from its equilibrium length, and the direction of the force is directed along the line joining the two masses. In other words, for the force $\mathbf{F}_1$ on the first particle we have:
$$
\mathbf{F}_1 = -k\left( |\mathbf{x}_1 - \mathbf{x}_2| - x_o\right)\frac{\mathbf{x}_1 - \mathbf{x}_2}{|\mathbf{x}_1 - \mathbf{x}_2|} = -k \left( 1 - \frac{x_o}{|\mathbf{x}_1 - \mathbf{x}_2|}\right) \left( \mathbf{x}_1 - \mathbf{x}_2 \right).
$$
I don't see how this equation, because of the term in the denominator, can be rewritten in a linear form.

For some reason I have been under the impression that the motion for a system of springs always possesses solutions in the form of superpositions of normal modes, but I can not reconcile this with the form of the equation of motion I show above.

Comment: We also know that, because of conservation of angular momentum, the equations of motion can be separated into an angular and radial equation, where the radial equation will possess a (nonlinear!) $\propto L/r^2$ centrifugal term, where $L$ is the angular momentum.

Comment: The equations of motion are independent of your choice the inertial system, thus you can rotate the inertial system so that the x axes is towards the spring your spring force is now $ -k(x_1-x_2-x_0)$ which is linear

Comment: what if the spring is rotating?

Comment: If it's rotating you can go to the rotating frame, as long as you include the appropriate pseudoforce.

Comment: You rotate with constant angle . This is static rotation

Comment: the equation is not linear in the rotating frame

Comment: Why not? In the co-rotating reference frame, I'd say all you have to do is account for the centrifugal force pushing them apart, which simply shifts the spring resting/equilibrium length. This way each force is linear.

Comment: the centrifugal force is nonlinear

Comment: OK, the oscillations about the CM would mean, for constant angular momentum, oscillating angular speed -> nonconstant equilibrium length, that's what you mean? You might be right, I'd have to try to calculate it to answer properly...